# How to sort this array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Array:

```
["6", "3", "1A", "4", "10", "1"]:
```

Expected output:

```
["1", "1A", "3", "4",, "6", "10"];
```

Putting the array through `parseInt` will break the code.
I'm using `sort(function(a,b){return a-b;})` to sort.

Whereas using it as it is will put `1A` at the end of the sorted list.

Comment: Are all entries guaranteed to have numeric components?

Comment: @JaredSmith No, all the entries aren't numeric, although, they might contain certain alphanumeric characters as such

Comment: So where would the element 'B' be placed in the example? At the end of it?

Comment: You need to explain your requirement for the sort criteria, because in most cases `1A > 10`

Comment: Is 1A hexadecimal?

Comment: @user22222 no, I mean is `itemInTheArray.match(/\d+/)` guaranteed to not fail?

Answer (score 5):

[localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) set to numeric should do the trick.

```js
var list = ["6", "3", "1A", "4", "10", "1"]

console.log(list)

var sorted = list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {
    numeric: true
  })
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks buddy!